# Parallel Requests or Queuing Like Node.js

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js

How can I get JavaScript to act "non-blocking" like Node.js on the client?  I currently have Node.js pushing me updates to the client through Socket.IO, while at the same time I have multiple AJAX calls fetching data onLoad, which seem to run in parallel, and then processing the result data, rendering it to my Knockout views, some jQuery action, etc...

But I keep running into blocking problems, for example where data is being pushed in from Node, but isn't being processed, while Javascript is processing the results of my AJAX callback results or other JS methods being run.  Ideally, I would love to be able to run multiple functions in parallel.

I realize JavaScript is single threaded, but using Node.js as a model, how can I fake "non-blocking" on the client?

Comment: Javascript is non-blocking, if you use it in an asynchronous way. If you send a single data stream through you Socket.IO, that is blocking. You should send small events, and then you can react in parallel. But if you send several megabytes of data at once, they will have to be dealt with before the socket can emit other events.
It sounds like you have deeper design issues.

Comment: Thanks guys!  Yes, the Node pushes through Socket.IO are very small JSON objects.  The AJAX calls are pulling down a lot of data though on load for the page.  Both the Node push and the AJAX request seem to be async.  

However, the blocking is happening anytime I run a JS function, and do something with the data I got from the Node push or Ajax pull.

Answer (score 1):

### WebWorkers

The HTML 5 spec allows for parallel processing using a construct called WebWorkers. You can find details on this specification at the following links (listed in what I believe to be order of usefulness):

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers
- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp